# How can i union sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have to queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '{$id}'
SELECT * FROM `post_votes` WHERE `post` = '{$id}' AND `user` = '{$user}'
```

Can I join them together into one query (some column names are similar) and get assoc array using mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN post_votes ON posts.id = post_votes.post WHERE posts.id = {$id} AND post_votes.user = '{$user}'` ? What is the reason to `UNION()` ?

Comment: @Jaquarh i have a lot of queries to MySQL so validation need 400-1000ms

Comment: @User11 The question is a bit unclear, at least to me. Can you share some sample data and the result you'd want to get for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand exactly your tables structures but I think what you are looking for is `UNION ALL`
So your query might look like:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '{$id}'*
UNION ALL
SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM `post_votes` WHERE `post` = '{$id}' AND `user` = '{$user}'
```

If posts and post_votes don't have same column names you will have to use aliases.
See https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/union_all.php fore more details